# Jade/Pug with Angular 2 - how to resolve conflict with # syntax?

Tags: angular, pug

### **Jade input**

```
div(#menu class="ui dropdown icon item")
```

### **Html output**

```
<div #menu="#menu" class="ui dropdown icon item">
```

***#menu="#menu"*** is wrong, the output i was expecting was just ***#menu***.

```
<div #menu class="ui dropdown icon item">
```

---

**The issue:**

Angular's [template reference variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#ref-vars) are in conflict with jade's [#idname syntax](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/).

**Version Infomation:**

- Jade 1.11.0
- Angular 2 rc4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should normally be able to fix it by explicitly telling Jade compiler to HTML5 doctype:

```
doctype html
div(#menu class="ui dropdown icon item")
```

Comment: It does the job, but it's not elegant in this case because i would have to add a *doctype html* tag to every *.jade* file that represents a component in angular 2.
I was looking for some kind of operator that would prevent the compiler from render a portion of code. For example **doNotRender="#menu"** compiles to **#menu** or something like that.

Comment: I think you could set up compilation with API and then use `jade.compile(template, {doctype: 'html'})`. Then you would not need to put it in every template.

Comment: Yes, brilliant. Do you know how could i use that conf line on the command line? i'm using **jade ./app --obj '{ doctype: 'html' }' -P -w** but it says that html is not defined...

Comment: You can use --doctype option: `jade ./app --doctype html -P -w`.

Answer (score 0):

according to [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars)

> Folks who don't like using the # character can use its canonical alternative, the ref- prefix. For example, we can declare the our phone variable using either #phone or ref-phone.

```
<!-- phone refers to the input element; pass its 'value' to an event handler -->
<input #phone placeholder="phone number">
<button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>

<!-- fax refers to the input element; pass its 'value' to an event handler -->
<input ref-fax placeholder="fax number">
<button (click)="callFax(fax.value)">Fax</button>
```

In your case use `ref-menu` instead of `#menu`

BTW @dfsq solution works fine with `doctype html`:

```
div(#menu class="ui dropdown icon item")
```

but this throws error (`#menu` *after* `class` attribute):

```
div(class="ui dropdown icon item" 
        #menu [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" 
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
)
```

So you need divide attributes with comma :

```
div(class="ui dropdown icon item", 
    #menu,
    [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']",
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
)
```

or better do it angular-way:

> Binding types other than interpolation have a target name to the left of the equal sign, either surrounded by punctuation ([], ()) or preceded by a prefix (bind-, on-, bindon-).